# Enable a textbox when the previous one is no longer empty

Tags: javascript, dom, user-interface

I've written this JavaScript code, which disables textboxes if the previous textbox is empty. This is so people enter the text in order — write first in the first textbox, only then the second textbox enables, write in the second, enable the third, etc. It also clears and disables any textboxes below the one that had its text deleted.

The code works as intended, but I'm afraid if my colleagues see it they will laugh at how it is written and the more textboxes it has the more spammy it gets. Please tell me how I can optimize this?

```
$q.find(".row1 :text, .row2 :text, .row3 :text").on("keyup", function(){

    var userRow1 = $q.find(".row1 :text")
    var userRow2 = $q.find(".row2 :text")
    var userRow3 = $q.find(".row3 :text")
    var userRow4 = $q.find(".row4 :text")
    
    if (userRow1.val().trim().length > 0) {
        userRow2.enable();  
    } else {
        userRow2.val("").disable().fclear;
        userRow3.val("").disable().fclear;
        userRow4.val("").disable().fclear;
    };
    
    if (userRow2.val().trim().length > 0) {
        userRow3.enable();  
    } else {
        userRow3.val("").disable().fclear;
        userRow4.val("").disable().fclear;
    };
    
    if (userRow3.val().trim().length > 0) {
        userRow4.enable();  
    } else {
        userRow4.val("").disable().fclear;
    };
    
}).trigger("keyup");
```

Comment: Can you also post your html ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does `$q` come from jQuery or a similar library? What is `fclear`?

Comment: Sorry, Alex HTML is not available. ".row1" ".row2" etc. just stand for the row classes while :text selects the textbox on that row.

Comment: Hi Sam, `$q` does come form jQuery, in the code I just use to to specify the current page/question. while the fclear function will just clear any text in the specified textbox.